# Get child element of span with certain attribute value with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I want to test with protractor if a popover pops up. This is the my html. The popover sits in the last child span:

```
<span tariff-popover="views/popovers/c2g/airport.html" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <span ng-transclude="">
        <span class="ng-scope">
           Flughafenpauschale
         </span>
     </span>
        &nbsp;
     <span popover-placement="right" popover-template="text" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="fa fa-info-circle">
     </span>
</span>
```

How do I select the last span? I need to select it based on the value of `tariff-popover` on the parent span. This is how I've tried to selet it:

```
it('should display the popover-content on mouseover', function() {
  var popover = element(by.css('span[tariff-popover=views/popovers/c2g/airport.html] > .fa.fa-info-circle'));

  console.log(popover.getInnerHtml());

  /* more tests here */

});
```

The console.log gives me errors as the css selector is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be quotes around the tariff-popover value. Try with this -

```
var popover = element(by.css('span[tariff-popover="views/popovers/c2g/airport.html"] > .fa.fa-info-circle'));
```

And moreover `.getInnerHtml()` will return a promise. So, you need to wait for it to return a value. Here's how -

```
popover.getInnerHtml().then(function(val){
    console.log(val);
});
```

Hope this helps.